# How to generate Control from HTML String in C# asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to convert my HTML String to control in C# asp.net  and I am getting this below error  "Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

I did searching since last five-6 hours. Already go through so many answers in the internet including Stackoverflow. But non of answers solved my query.
Thanks in advance for replay

```
protected TextBox t2;
protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
{

String Str ="<input  type="text" id="txtID" class="form-control" runat="server"  />";
LiteralControl lt = new LiteralControl();
lt.Text = Str;
t1.Controls.Add(lt);
t2 = (TextBox)t1.FindControl("txtID");
t2.Text = "Maddsf";
}
```

Comment: That is definitely your code? I am surprised it compiles.

Comment: When you debug through it, is `t2` null?

Comment: The short answer is that `LiteralControl` is not what you want to use here. I think you have misunderstood what it is for. See the duplicate I suggest.

Comment: You can't generate a control that runs at the server side by adding a string to your document.  Instead, why don't you just declare it in your markup and selectively hide/show it?

Answer (score 0):

The following line will give you the error:

```
t2.Text = "Maddsf";
```

**Cause**: Because the **FindControl()** method gives you a web control. However, **txtID** is not a web control and that's why **FindControl()** method fails to return a web control (**TextBox** in this case) and instead returns a **null** value. What you have assigned to the **Text** property of the **Literal** control **lt** is an input text field which would be successfully rendered by the browser. However, ASP.NET has no knowledge that the control exists.

**Solution**: For this very same reason, you would be able to get a reference to the control in JavaScript. Something like this:

```
document.getElementById("txtID").value = "Maddsf";
```